# Add numeric classes to specific lists with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, children, addclass

Im trying to add dynamic classes to a couple of lists with the following code:

```
$("ul.list").children().each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("item-" + (i+1));
});
```

If the page contains more than one list the numeric values continues to increase. But I would like to reset the count for every list like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item-1></li>
    <li class="item-2></li>
    <li class="item-3></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li class="item-1></li>
    <li class="item-2></li>
    <li class="item-3></li>
</ul>
```

How do I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .each() twice, once for the parent ul elements and then for the children:

```
$("ul.list").each(function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("item-" + (i+1));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do an each on the class and then inside the each process the children.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's each function to do a nested loop: http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/FxmC7/